# WooCommerce dynamic ID pricing

Tags: javascript, wordpress, woocommerce

I am trying to show prices of a product that is select previously by analyzing a form.

With a shortcode I can display the price of a product by it's ID, but I have to hard code it on a section.

This works...

```js
<script type="text/javascript">
var x = "4145";
    document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function () {
      document.getElementById('input').innerHTML = "[woocommerce_price id=4145]";
   })
</script>
```

And this doesn't...

```js
<script type="text/javascript">
var x = "4145";
    document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function () {
      document.getElementById('input').innerHTML = "[woocommerce_price id=" + x + "]";
   })
</script>
```

How can I make this work on the client side?

Comment: Can you try replacing the declaration of x inside the function?

Comment: @Redfx same thing, it gets an empty value, nothing

Comment: Mmm.. Can you try to use something like x.toString(), x.value() etc. and tracking what the x returns by logging it onto console via the Inspector (F12 to open it)? I have tried to get your code running on jsbin but couldn't :/. Also even though your code works in the first example, I have seen on the documentation: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/EventTarget/addEventListener that they pass false as the 3rd argument on addEventListener. Can you also add it and try ?

Comment: @Redfx I noticed that it also does not work if I separate the string, like "[woocommerce_price id=" + "4145" + "]"

Comment: Oh then can you try to concatenate the String outside of the innerHTML assignment?

Comment: @Redfx That's what I thought, but now it just prints out the whole string and does not act as shortcode...

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/154802/discussion-between-igor-silveira-and-red-fx).

Comment: Shortcodes are run on the server. Javascript runs on the client browser. In the code you have the shortcode is the string '[woocommerce_price id=" + x + "]' when the server evaluates the shortcode. After this evaluation is done and sent to the client browser you are trying to set the parameter to the shortcode in the client browser. This cannot work as the  server has already done its work. You need to study AJAX for a solution to this problem.